# Why does the android studios layout preview look different

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

When i first create an android studio project, there should be a pre made layout preview in the activity_main.xml, but i only see a grey screen with the words 'Hello World'.

Here is what it looks like...[image]

but it should look like this...

[image]

How do i fix this? I tried restarting my computer and pressing reload in android studios, but nothing is working. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Probably your activity is having such Theme. or that could be the default color of Android Studio.

Comment: A few days ago, it was working perfectly. Now its looking different. When i run the app on a device, it looks the way its suppose to. So why is it looking different in android studio?

Comment: Click that app theme button. Choose the theme you want. It will preview the theme that is set. Also make sure to build the project first.

Answer (score 0):

This can be because you have changed the theme of the app in android studio in **preview** window